# Determine failing command in Bash pipe when working with set -o pipefail

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm using `set -o pipefail` in my scripts as usual. That works perfectly well and as documented for something like

`curl ... | jq ... | psql ...`

However, is there a way to determine which command along a pipeline actually failed the whole thing?

I'm looking into this for the sole purpose of more concise logging but couldn't find any documentation thereon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `PIPESTATUS` builtin array:

```bsh
true | true | false | true | true
declare -p PIPESTATUS
```

```bsh
declare -a PIPESTATUS=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="1" [3]="0" [4]="0")
```